# Ставится ли запятая перед "как"?

Tags: запятые

> Образцы запрессовывают(,) как показано на рисунке 4.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Образцы запрессовывают [**так**], **как** показано на рисунке 4.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с местоименной связью, указательное слово "так" опущено.

Answer (score -1):

Нет, не ставится.

> 4. Сравнительный оборот с союзом ***как*** не выделяется запятыми:
>    (...) 4) если сравнительный оборот входит в сказуемое (образует именную
>    часть составного сказуемого) или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым
>    (обычно в этих случаях сказуемое не выражает необходимого смысла без
>    сравнительного оборота): *Одни как изумруд, другие как коралл* (Крылов);
>    *Она сама ходила как дикая* (Гончаров); *Как ребёнок душою я стал*
>    (Тургенев); *«Город как город», — хладнокровно заметил Базаров*
>    (Тургенев); *Гамзат вышел из палатки, подошёл к стремени Умма-Хана и
>    принял его как хана* (Л. Толстой); *Наш сад как проходной двор* (Чехов); *Повести мои оценивались как смешные или скверные анекдоты* (Горький); *Все относились к Ване как к своему человеку* (Пришвин); *Поэма была произнесена как признание*
>    (Федин); *Он говорил о привычных вещах как о чём-то необычайно
>    интересном* (Паустовский).
>
> http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147,3

Comment: Считаю, что приведенное правило совершенно не подходит в данном случае. Где именная часть сказуемого или тесная связь с ним? Нет ни одного примера, близкого к предложению из вопроса. Там две основы: ***запрессовывают*** – неопределенно-личная часть, а ***показано*** – безличная.

Comment: Два односоставных предложения.

Comment: @Егор Сальков, КАК - это сравнительный союз?  Что с чем сравниваем? Можно использовать синонимы будто, словно?

Comment: «Два односоставных предложения» — с чего вдруг? Там обыкновенное сложное сказуемое: «запрессовывают как показано». Связь «как показано» с «запрессовывают» именно тесная, ибо важно не только запрессовывание, а не менее важно, чтобы это делалось как показано. Именной части сказуемого нету, да, — а что, про составное глагольное сказуемое вы не слышали?

Comment: Sharon, идите к Розенталю.

Comment: "Как показано" – это иллюстрация (так и написано: "на рисунке"), а не инструкция к запрессовыванию.

Comment: Спасибо, что не так далеко.:)   Пожалуй, я зайду  в раздел  «Цельные по смыслу сочетания», вот и адресок есть.   http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146  Делай как знаешь (=по-своему). Запятая не нужна. Это устойчивый оборот на основе придаточного предложения, по значению он равен  слову.  Но устойчивость у них ненадежная, и они легко превращаются в придаточные. Еще можно сказать: «делай как положено», но вряд ли  «делай как показано на рисунке 4». :))

Comment: «"Как показано" – это иллюстрация (так и написано: "на рисунке"), а не инструкция к запрессовыванию» — а иллюстрация — не инструкция? Просто картинка для оживления материала, да? «Спасибо, что не так далеко.:)» — не благодарите: на самом деле для многих это ОЧЕНЬ далеко, гораздо дальше, чем «к чёрту». Так что многие наверняка по-настоящему не дойдут.

Comment: Егор, не путайте картинки, рисунки и инструкции с грамматическим строем предложения – это всего лишь лексическое наполнение, а мы с вами обсуждаем грамматику.  Это СПП с придаточным обстоятельственным, связь местоименная вида ТАК…КАК. Придаточное раскрывает содержание (опущенного) указательного местоимения  ТАК, союзное слово КАК  как средство связи. Хотите превратить придаточное в обычное обстоятельство?  Боюсь, что это УТОПИЯ, потому что оснований для этого нет ни малейших. Нет у вашего мнимого обстоятельства «фразеологической цельности», а это его  (НУ И ВАШ ТОЖЕ) единственный шанс...

Comment: Я всё меньше сомневаюсь в том, что до Розенталя вы не дойдёте :))